# ElasticSearch hive SerializationError handler

Tags: elasticsearch, hadoop, hive, elasticsearch-hadoop

Using Elastic search version 6.8.0

```
hive> select * from provider1;
OK
{"id","k11",}
{"id","k12",}
{"id","k13",}
{"id","k14",}
{"id":"K1","name":"Ravi","salary":500}
{"id":"K2","name":"Ravi","salary":500}
{"id":"K3","name":"Ravi","salary":500}
{"id":"K4","name":"Ravi","salary":500}
{"id":"K5","name":"Ravi","salary":500}
{"id":"K6","name":"Ravi","salary":"sdfgg"}
{"id":"K7","name":"Ravi","salary":"sdf"}
{"id":"k8"}
{"id":"K9","name":"r1","salary":522}
{"id":"k10","name":"r2","salary":53}
Time taken: 0.179 seconds, Fetched: 14 row(s)
```

---

```
ADD JAR /home/smrafi/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.8.0/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.8.0.jar;
CREATE external TABLE hive_es_with_handler( data STRING)
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES(
  'es.resource' = 'test_eshadoop/healthCareProvider',
  'es.nodes' = 'vpc-pid-pre-prod-es-cluster-b7thvqfj3tp45arxl34gge3yyi.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com',
  'es.input.json' = 'yes',
  'es.index.auto.create' = 'true',
  'es.write.operation'='upsert',
  'es.nodes.wan.only' = 'true',
  'es.port' = '443',
  'es.net.ssl'='true',
  'es.batch.size.entries'='1',
  'es.mapping.id' ='id',
  'es.batch.write.retry.count'='-1',
  'es.batch.write.retry.wait'='60s',
  'es.write.rest.error.handlers' = 'es, ignoreBadRecords',
  'es.write.data.error.handlers' = 'customLog',
  'es.write.data.error.handler.customLog' = 'com.verisys.elshandler.CustomLogOnError',
  'es.write.rest.error.handler.es.client.resource'="error_es_index/error",
  'es.write.rest.error.handler.es.return.default'='HANDLED',
  'es.write.rest.error.handler.log.logger.name' = 'BulkErrors',
  'es.write.data.error.handler.log.logger.name' = 'SerializationErrors',
  'es.write.rest.error.handler.ignoreBadRecords' = 'com.verisys.elshandler.IgnoreBadRecordHandler',
  'es.write.rest.error.handler.es.return.error'='HANDLED');
insert into hive_es_with_handler10 select * from provider1;
```

Below is exception trace, it failed complaining the error.handler index is not present

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.EsHadoopSerializationException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value  at [Source: [B@1e3f0aea; line: 1, column: 7]
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.json.JacksonJsonParser.nextToken(JacksonJsonParser.java:95)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ParsingUtils.doFind(ParsingUtils.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ParsingUtils.values(ParsingUtils.java:151)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.field.JsonFieldExtractors.process(JsonFieldExtractors.java:213) 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.JsonTemplatedBulk.preProcess(JsonTemplatedBulk.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.TemplatedBulk.write(TemplatedBulk.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsSerDe.serialize(EsSerDe.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:550)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value  at [Source: [B@1e3f0aea; line: 1, column: 7]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:500)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.json.JacksonJsonParser.nextToken(JacksonJsonParser.java:93)   ... 22 more
```

I tried to use the custom SerializationErrorHandler But it is of no use and Handler is not coming into context, Its completely stopping the job instead of continuing for the good records even After having default (HANDLED as the constant)

Comment: According to the error, you have a field/record that isn't valid JSON

Comment: Yes thats correct, I intentionally gave bad records to test the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/6.8/errorhandlers.html#errorhandlers-serialization, But in the documentation it says hive doesnt have support, Thanks @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have invalid JSON

Mentioned in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/6.8/errorhandlers.html#errorhandlers-serialization), this is not handled by Hive

> Serialization Error Handlers are not yet available for Hive. Elasticsearch for Apache Hadoop uses Hive’s SerDe constructs to convert data into bulk entries before being sent to the output format. SerDe objects do not have a cleanup method that is called when the object ends its lifecycle. Because of this, we do not support serialization error handlers in Hive as they cannot be closed at the end of the job execution

Comment: Yes agree, Have seen the doc yesterday